# How can I load an XML local file to postgres without pg_read_file?

Tags: postgresql, windows-10

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION j_f_sync_from_xml()
RETURNS boolean AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
myxml    xml;
datafile text := 'ABBATE_EMANUELE.xml';
BEGIN

myxml := pg_read_file(datafile, 0, 100000000); 

CREATE TABLE james AS
SELECT (xpath('//some_id/text()', x))[1]::text AS id
FROM   unnest(xpath('/xml/path/to/datum', myxml)) x;
END;
$BODY$ language plpgsql;
```

pg_read_file doesn't function because i can't write on server machine.
Anyone has the idea how to use a local file in postgres?

Comment: please update with details that your client is on windows

Comment: i'm on windows 10

Answer (score -1):

using psql:

```
create table xml(body text);
\copy xml from 'C:\temp\notes.xml';
select string_agg(body,'')::xml from xml;
```

results:

```
                                                   string_agg
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 <note><to>Tove</to><from>Jani</from><heading>Reminder</heading><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body></note>
```

or same with pgadmin:

[image]

after that same:

```
select string_agg(body,'')::xml from xml;
```